# create rounded corner border in android with three colors for a layout

Tags: android, android-layout, border

create rounded corner border in android with three colors for a layout

i want to create a layout with rounded borders and also have those border in three colors like the outer most border would be green , middle border blue and the last inner border again green how can this be achieved

i have tried this code to create a rou

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />

    <stroke
        android:width="3dip"
        android:color="#B1BCBE" />

    <corners android:radius="10dip" />

    <padding
        android:bottom="0dip"
        android:left="0dip"
        android:right="0dip"
        android:top="0dip" />

</shape>
```

but have can we add multiple borders to the same layout

Comment: only "rounded borders" in three colors? or the whole shape?

Comment: does it have to be xml only?

Comment: can try either way in java as well as xml, would be great if you could give an example in both might be useful for others also

Comment: i never do such thing in xml: xml is too "stupid" for such things, see below answers...

Comment: then how can it be done in java

Answer (score 0):

You can use the layer-list for multiple color corner like-

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:id="@+id/shape_1">
        <shape  android:shape="rectangle" >

            <solid android:color="@color/cardview_background"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@+id/shape_2" android:bottom="1dp">
        <shape  android:shape="rectangle" >

            <solid android:color="@color/blue_main"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@+id/shape_3" android:bottom="2dp">
        <shape  android:shape="rectangle" >

            <solid android:color="@color/cardview_background"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use layer-list

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<!-- Outer Border -->
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners android:radius="4dp"/>
        <padding android:bottom="4dp" android:left="4dp" android:right="4dp" android:top="4dp"/>
        <stroke android:color="@color/pull_to_refresh_color2" android:width="4dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>


<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <padding android:bottom="4dp" android:left="4dp" android:right="4dp" android:top="4dp"/>
        <stroke android:color="@color/blue_font_dark" android:width="4dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <stroke android:color="@color/red_dark" android:width="4dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

well thanks to both harish and sanjeet this solved the issue , i have changed the radius at for each item so as to avoid any white space being shown at the rounded corner , here is the code that worked perfecly for me

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <corners android:radius="20dip" />

            <padding
                android:bottom="4dp"
                android:left="4dp"
                android:right="4dp"
                android:top="4dp" />

            <stroke
                android:width="4dp"
                android:color="#04B404" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <corners android:radius="15dip" />

            <padding
                android:bottom="4dp"
                android:left="4dp"
                android:right="4dp"
                android:top="4dp" />

            <stroke
                android:width="4dp"
                android:color="#58D3F7" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <corners android:radius="10dip" />

            <padding
                android:bottom="4dp"
                android:left="4dp"
                android:right="4dp"
                android:top="4dp" />

            <stroke
                android:width="4dp"
                android:color="#04B404" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```